# How do I get the @AuthenticatedPrincipal from a web socket simpUser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I'm trying to get logged in users' details who are connected via websocket on Spring Boot 2. To do this, I'm currently using SimpUserRegistry to find a list of connected SimpUsers.

Since Spring Boot 2.4, I noticed the SimpUser class has a getPrincipal() method that returns a generic Principal object. As each user is supposed to login via Spring Security's mechanisms, I thought I was able to cast it to Spring Security's UserDetails to get the logged in user , but I realize it wasn't the case.

Does anyone know how I can make use of getPrincipal or other ways to get logged in userDetails?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's make it clear that, to use `getPrincipal()` with websocket, you have to implement **websocket authentication and authorization** through `Interceptor` (as far as I know SpringSecurity doesn't do this automatically).

After doing the above correctly, you can now use the `getPrincipal ()` method. It will return [The identity of the principal being authenticated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.20.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) (maybe Username, email,...)

You can use code that looks like this:

```
@MessageMapping("/test")
public void doSomething(@Payload AppMessage appMessage, Principal principal) {
    String username = principal.getName();
    // find userDetail with username here
}
```